# Devise User Review/Rating System in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rating

I'm trying to create a review system on users in rails.  I want one user to be able to rate another user on their profile page in devise.  I've tried a few different methods but I am fairly new to rails and haven't been able to accomplish this.

Right now I have default devise views but no user profile page. I'd like users to review a another user on 5 or so different issues.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you can use the association called `has_many through` association : 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Your models should look like that "

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates
  has_many :rated_users, through: :rates, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :rated_user_id # The users this user has rated
  has_many :rated_by_users, through: :rates, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :rating_user_id # The users that have rated this client
end

class Rates < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rating_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :rated_user, class_name: "User"
end
```

And your migrations :

```
class createRates < ActiveRecord::Migration


  def change
    create_table :changes do |t|
      t.belongs_to :rated_user
      t.belongs_to :rating_user
      t.integer :value
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Oxynum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2121499/oxynum) - great concept! After adding models and applying migrations, starts with templates. Starting point for you is a users_controller.rb. Probably, you already have a 'show' action inside UsersController. This action available for authenticated users.
Modify this action to smth like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :load_ratable, :only => [:show, :update_rating] 

  def show        
    # Renders app/views/users/show.html.erb with user profile and rate controls
  end

  def update_rating        
    my_rate_value = params[:value] == 'up' ? +1 : -1        
    if  @rated_by_me.blank?
      Rate.create(rated_user: @userProfile, rating_user: @user, value: my_rate_value)
      flash[:notice] = "You rated #{@userProfile.name}: #{params[:value]}"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You already rated #{@userProfile.name}" 
    end
    render action: 'show'
  end

  protected:
    def load_ratable
      @userProfile = User.find(params[:id]) # - is a viewed profile.
      @user = current_user                  # - is you
      @rated_by_me = Rate.where(rated_user: @userProfile, rating_user: @user)
    end
end
```

Add to routes:

```
get 'users/update_rating/:value' => 'user#update_rating'
```

Start rails server, Log In, and try to change rating directly:

```
  http://localhost:3000/users/update_rating/up
```